# Select all rows as one table type object in pure Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table type:

`CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_id AS TABLE OF NUMBER(12);`

I need to select IDs from table and return them as single tab_id. In PL/SQL I would use BULK COLLECT INTO, but I need it in **pure SQL**. I need the query to return the tab_id object directly.

I tried:

```
WITH src AS ( 
SELECT 1 AS token FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS token FROM DUAL
)
SELECT tab_id( token ) FROM src
```

But this returns two rows of type `tab_id`, first contains value 1 and second contains value 2.
I need the query to return only one row, containing both values in one `tab_id`.

I also tried following version without success:

```
WITH src AS ( 
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT tab_id( SELECT * FROM src ) FROM DUAL -- I got ORA-00936
SELECT tab_id( ( SELECT * FROM src ) ) FROM DUAL -- I got ORA-01427
```

Is there a way how to select all values into one table type?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9oF3KZBauZY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `COLLECT` function with `CAST`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ffbb42/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_id AS TABLE OF NUMBER(12);
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH src
AS (
    SELECT 1 AS token FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS token  FROM DUAL
    )
SELECT CAST(COLLECT(token) AS tab_id)
FROM src
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ffbb42/7/0)**:

```
| CAST(COLLECT(TOKEN)ASTAB_ID) |
|------------------------------|
|                          1,2 |
```